# Run two scripts with init.d

Tags: init.d, teamspeak

I have a start script for TeamSpeak3 server in `/etc/init.d` that is run at the boot time.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ts3
# Required-Start:    $network mysql
# Required-Stop:     $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: TeamSpeak3 Server Daemon
# Description:       Starts/Stops/Restarts the TeamSpeak Server Daemon
### END INIT INFO

set -e

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="TeamSpeak3 Server"
NAME=teamspeak3-server
USER=teamspeak3
DIR=/opt/teamspeak3-server
OPTIONS=inifile=ts3server.ini
DAEMON=$DIR/ts3server_startscript.sh
#PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Gracefully exit if the package has been removed.
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

sleep 2
sudo -u $USER $DAEMON $1 $OPTIONS
```

And I need this to happen:

1. Run a script `./MyScript` that exits immediately and is located in TS3 directory
2. Wait some time
3. Run the actual daemon that will stay running

I am not really good with Unix scripting, I just need to run a server with this. I might also mention that I am running latest Ubuntu.

Thanks for help, krejcar25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple just run it before the command that run the TS3 `DAEMON` in the last line in your script then set `sleep` command for let's say for 5 sec for example and the script will be like that:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ts3
# Required-Start:    $network mysql
# Required-Stop:     $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: TeamSpeak3 Server Daemon
# Description:       Starts/Stops/Restarts the TeamSpeak Server Daemon
### END INIT INFO

set -e

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="TeamSpeak3 Server"
NAME=teamspeak3-server
USER=teamspeak3
DIR=/opt/teamspeak3-server
OPTIONS=inifile=ts3server.ini
DAEMON=$DIR/ts3server_startscript.sh
#PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Gracefully exit if the package has been removed.
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

sleep 2
#####################################################
$DIR/MyScript
sleep 5
#####################################################
sudo -u $USER $DAEMON $1 $OPTIONS
```

the `$DER` var refer to the TS3 service directory `/opt/teamspeak3-server`